# error: 'this.adapter.clients' when using sailsjs publishCreate

Tags: sails.js

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: this.adapter.clients is not a function
at Namespace.clients (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:253:16)
at Object.addRoomMembersToRooms (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/lib/sails.sockets/add-room-members-to-rooms.js:50:42)
at introduce (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js:1342:23)
at wrapper [as introduce] (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
at publishCreateSingle (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js:1237:16)
at /Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js:1069:16
at arrayEach (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:1289:13)
at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3345:13)
at publishCreate (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js:1068:11)
at wrapper [as publishCreate] (/Users/oteng/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
```

when i try to publishCreate after a record creation in sailsjs
this is the create function

```
Tbl_Direct_Cash.create({
            amount_paid: amount_paid,
            payment_type: payment_type,
            payment_ID: payment_ID,
            tbl_user: tbl_user
        }).exec(function (e, r) {
            if (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return res.ok('TRANSACTION FAILED....TRY AGAIN');
            } else {

                //console.log(e);
                Tbl_Direct_Cash.publishCreate({id: 40});
                return res.ok('TRANSACTION SAVED');

            }
        });
```

and this is my watch method

```
notify: function (req, res) {
    if (req.isSocket) {
        Tbl_Direct_Cash.watch(req);
        Tbl_Deduction.watch(req);
        // Gene.watch(req);
        return res.ok()
    }
}
```

the create request is sent from a mobile app whiles the notify request

```
io.socket.on('connect', function () {
    io.socket.get('/dashboard/notify', function (e, r) {
        console.log(e, r);
    });
})
```

is sent from the admin client

Comment: What version of Sails are you using?  And are you using the built-in memory adapter for sockets, or `socket.io-redis`?

Comment: we are using sails version: 0.12.7 and `socket.io-redis`

Comment: What version of socket.io-redis?

Comment: the socket.io-redis version is 0.1.4

Comment: That's incredibly old.  The latest version of socket.io-redis is 4.0.0.  Try upgrading to the latest version (`npm install socket.io-redis@latest --save`) and see if that fixes your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My socket.io-redis version was very old. Updating it to the latest version solved the problem